# Time Deley Loop BlueJ

Tags: java, bluej

java.until.cocurrent.TimeUnit.SECOND.sleep(12)-

can someone correct this because its not working in the system. it keeps saying class, interface or enum expected.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to correct the whole thing.
1. `until` --> `util`
2. `cocurrent`--> `concurrent`
3. `SECOND` --> `SECONDS`.

Comment: java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(12);
public class Comp_Project
{public static void main() 
  { System.out.println("A");
      
     System.out.println("B");
    }
}                                                                                                                                               Its still not working

Comment: @NiyathiMeghana Please do not copy-paste code in comment. Use edit option. The `sleep()` is expected to be inside the `main()` method not above class declaration.

Comment: @RajeevSreedharan i do not understand. Can i have an example?

Comment: I wont post this as answer, this is more typo. You can use like this :  
public class Comp_Project {public static void main() { java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(12); System.out.println("A"); System.out.println("B"); } }

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your programm to "sleep" between printing strings "A" and "B", you should try the following (here are two possible implementations, both require to import java.util).

```
import java.util.*; //Double-check if you have imported this to your project


//1st code option
public class Comp_Project{
    public static void main() {

        System.out.println("A");

        try{
            java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(12);
            //try to sleep before printing "B"
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println(e); //prints exception if something goes wrong
        }  

        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

//2nd code option
public class Comp_Project extends Thread {
    public static void main() {

        System.out.println("A");

        try{
            Thread.sleep(12); //try to sleep before printing "B"
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println(e); //prints exception if something goes wrong
        }  

        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! If it works, don't forget to accept my answer as correct :)

Comment: is there a way that B can be printed in place of A after the time delay?

Comment: I didn't get exactly what you need, so I have three suggestions.: 1- Swap printing lines, so B will be printed before A. 2- Print A once again after B by adding another println command after B. 3- Add the whole code (println+try+catch+println) on a while command so it will loop until a desired condition is reached.

Comment: i mean like- the program prints 'A', then the time delay plays. After the time delay, 'A' dissapears and 'B' is printed in its place.

Comment: If you are developing a console application, there is no way to "erase" what has already been printed. My suggestion is to print many "/n" (break lines). This way, anything that had been printed before would be hidden on the console. Then, you could print anything you want in the desired order.

Comment: no like, when it moves from one screen to the next. For example- you have the first output screen which shows the name of the game. it than moves to the next output screen which asks you if its single player or multi player.

Comment: Which kind of interface are you using on your project?

Comment: meaning? i'm using blueJ

Comment: How do I clear the terminal?
There are two different ways to clear the terminal in BlueJ. You can get BlueJ to automatically clear the terminal before every interactive method call. To do this, activate the 'Clear screen at method call' option in the 'Options' menu of the terminal. You can also clear the terminal programmatically from within your program. Printing a formfeed character (unicode 000C) clears the BlueJ terminal, for example:
System.out.print('\u000C'); Extracted from https://www.bluej.org/faq.html